# I tried to run this query but it shows Subquery return more than 1 row

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT name
FROM test.projectusermap p
WHERE projectid IN(
    IF(1 = 1, (
        SELECT ProjectId
        FROM test.projectusermap
    ), (
        SELECT ProjectId
        FROM test.projectusermap
        WHERE name = 'ravi'
    ))
)
```

Comment: `IF(1=1...` means...what? Are you expecting that to be false at some point in the future?

Comment: @tadman: It could've generated via some other code.

Comment: This might be better with a `JOIN`.

Comment: If it's generated by some other code, that some other code should be responsible for putting in either query A or query B, but not both.

Comment: @tadman: True, but it was just a theory :)

Comment: @RocketHazmat It's a reasonable explanation, yeah.

Comment: I think a better question would be what do you want to happen if 1 = 1, do you want to return all rows where name <> 'ravi' or is the ProjectID dependent on the IF statement. the IF statement is what's messing with you. It is unclear what you want to return in the Query A based on a conditional IF. Your question is Subquery returns more than 1 row, which of course it is unless you tell it what to return.

Answer (score 0):

You would need something like this

```
SELECT name
FROM   test.projectusermap p
WHERE  projectid IN(SELECT ProjectId
                    FROM   test.projectusermap
                    WHERE  ( 1 = 1 ) /*I assume this boolean condition 
                                      is just a placeholder for testing
                                       and won't always be this*/
                            OR name = 'ravi')
```

Comment: i write if(1=1) just only want to know when my condition is true then result should be according to that

Comment: He's saying that IF ProjectID = 1 then return ProjectID 1, but the sub-query doesn't inherit the conditional IF, it just returns what it returns...That's why it needs to match.

Comment: @Hituptony - That's your interpretation. Mine is that `1 = 1` is just an arbitrary boolean. When the boolean is true they want `IN (all projectids)` when it is false they want  `IN (projectids for ravi)`

Comment: I see what you're saying. As does everyone else, just approaching it from a different angle since he hasn't selected an answer yet...but I hear you man..

Answer (score 0):

Well number 1 thing I see is that `IF 1=1` then It's going to be the results of Query A, Query A doesn't have a WHERE clause so it's going to return all ProjectID's in the Project table.

Otherwise It's going to return Project ID of 'ravi' assuming Ravi only has one Project ID and it is the primary key of that table.

I think you can solve the whole returning multiple rows issue by putting a WHERE clause in the Query A

Your `IF 1=1` Is saying where ProjectID IN( '1'), but your sub-query doesn't see that. You need to tell Query A to only return ProjectID 1 where ProjectID = 1 regardless of your IF statement BEFORE the sub-query, as the sub-query is independent of your initial WHERE clause, and the conditional IF statement.

```
SELECT name
FROM test.projectusermap
WHERE projectid IN(
    IF(1 = 1, (
        SELECT ProjectId
        FROM test.projectusermap WHERE ProjectID = 1
    ), (
        SELECT ProjectId
        FROM test.projectusermap
        WHERE name = 'ravi'
    ))
)
```

Also, took out Alias on projectusermap, because you don't use it with sub_query.

Another way to put it would be.

```
SELECT name FROM test.projectusermap WHERE projectID IN (SELECT ProjectID from test.projectusermap WHERE (1=1 or Name = Ravi) order by 1)
```

Comment: This is based on a lot of assumptions 1. ProjectID is primary key, and Query B won't return more than one row. 2. The issue lies in the Query A + IF statement. Without the IF, Query A just needs to be defined to return 1 row, because in this case, you cannot return more than one row.

Answer (score -1):

I think a `JOIN` might be better here

```
SELECT name
FROM test.projectusermap p
JOIN test.projectusermap p2 ON p.projectid = p2.ProjectId
WHERE p2.name = 'ravi'
```

Comment: i just want to know how select query work in IN clause

Comment: @user3258573: The issue might because of the `IF`.  Try just `WHERE projectid IN(SELECT ProjectId FROM test.projectusermap)`.